# Sending purchased items details to the PayPal?

Tags: java, android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I need to send the list of item purchased and whose payments are being done using Paypal so that the buyer as well as the vendor can see that what products have the been purchased or sold. Here is the snippet of what I did for the same, by following the  [Github code of PayPalCheckout](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/SampleApp/src/main/java/com/paypal/example/paypalandroidsdkexample/SampleActivity.java) but I get [image: We'are sorry dialog] each time. Here is my code snippet

```
private PayPalPayment prepareFinalCart() {

    List<PayPalItem> productsInCart = new ArrayList<>();
    double price;


    for (Program program : mPrograms) {
        if (null != program.programPrices.get(program.selectedPriceIndex).priceAfterDiscount) {
            price = program.programPrices.get(program.selectedPriceIndex).priceAfterDiscount;
        } else {
            price = program.programPrices.get(program.selectedPriceIndex).price;
        }
        PayPalItem item = new PayPalItem(program.type, 1, //Quantity
                new BigDecimal(price), //price
                Config.DEFAULT_CURRENCY, // currency
                 + String.valueOf(program.id)); // stock keeping unit

        productsInCart.add(item);
    }


    if (App.sCouponDetails != null) {
        App.sCouponDetails.calculateDiscount(mFinalCost);
    }


    PayPalItem[] items = new PayPalItem[productsInCart.size()];
    items = productsInCart.toArray(items);

    // Total amount
    BigDecimal subtotal = new BigDecimal(mFinalCost);

    // If you have shipping cost, add it here
    BigDecimal shipping = new BigDecimal("0.0");

    // If you have tax, add it here
    BigDecimal tax = new BigDecimal("0.0");

    PayPalPaymentDetails paymentDetails = new PayPalPaymentDetails(shipping, subtotal, tax);

    BigDecimal amount = subtotal.add(shipping).add(tax);


    // Getting Purchased Programs type
    StringBuilder programsType = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < mPrograms.size(); i++) {
        if (i == mPrograms.size() - 1) {
            programsType.append(mPrograms.get(i).type);
        } else {
            programsType.append(mPrograms.get(i).type).append(",");
        }
    }

    PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(amount, Config.DEFAULT_CURRENCY, "Total Amount: "/*programsType.toString()*/, Config.PAYMENT_INTENT);


    payment.items(items).paymentDetails(paymentDetails);


    // Custom field like invoice_number etc.,
    //payment.custom("This is text that will be associated with the payment that the app can use.");

    return payment;
}
```

Please suggest what's the issue here ?

Comment: Need to see the raw request that is getting generated from this code and sent to PayPal.

Comment: These is the item being added in PayPalPayment . `PayPalItem(name=Chinx Tier, quantity=1, price=79.950000, currency=USD, sku-2086) `

Comment: Okay, but that is not what I asked for.  We need to see exactly what is getting sent to PayPal.  Maybe the PayPalItem function is doing something funny with the data.  Maybe something else is filtering the data somehow and the request is getting funky data in it that PayPal doesn't like.  The first step in troubleshooting this is to see exactly what we're sending to PayPal.  Not what we think we're sending to PayPal.  If the raw request looks good, then we could move to next steps, but that is the first step.

Comment: Here is the Json String of PayPalPayment which is then being send to PaymentActivity of Paypal. `{"b":28.8629,"c":"USD","d":"Ching Flix,Syncers Flix","f":{"b":28.8629,"c":0.0,"d":0.0},"g":"sale","h":[{"b":"Ching Flix","c":1,"d":12,"e":"USD","f":"sku-6167"},{"b":"Syncers Flix","c":1,"d":20.0700,"e":"USD","f":"sku-6498"}],"i":false}`

Comment: That is not the format that PayPal would accept.  You have a/b/c/d as the parameter names..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually those b/c/d/f etc parameters are from PayPalPayment class. I just given its Json format.
Here is what PayPalPayment class looks like-[image: PayPalPayment.java]

Comment: error- ` request failed with server response:{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"transactions.item_list.items","issue":"Currency amount must be non-negative number, may optionally contain exactly 2 decimal places separated by '.', optional thousands separator ',', limited to 7 digits before the decimal point and currency which is a valid ISO Currency Code"}],"message":"Invalid request - see details","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"47cd8c53de5e8"}`

Answer (score 1):

solved. Above code was correct the price value was more than of 7 digits after decimal that was giving an error code 400 (VALIDATION_ERROR). But now handled .

Answer (score 0):

So the JSON string you've provided is:

```
{
   "b":28.8629,
   "c":"USD",
   "d":"Ching Flix,Syncers Flix",
   "f":{
      "b":28.8629,
      "c":0.0,
      "d":0.0
   },
   "g":"sale",
   "h":[
      {
         "b":"Ching Flix",
         "c":1,
         "d":12,
         "e":"USD",
         "f":"sku-6167"
      },
      {
         "b":"Syncers Flix",
         "c":1,
         "d":20.0700,
         "e":"USD",
         "f":"sku-6498"
      }
   ],
   "i":false
}
```

This is not a format that PayPal will accept.  Where are these b/c/d/f/etc. parameter names coming from?

You need to fix the request so it matches PayPal's format.